# Symony QueryBuilder

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to use createQueryBuilder, to make valid query. 
I want to get all Organizers, that have partOfSearchText and have some city_id

```
 $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Organizers');
        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->where('o.name LIKE :partOfSearchText')
            ->andWhere('o.cities = :city_id')
            ->setParameter('partOfSearchText', '%'.$partOfSearchText.'%')
            ->setParameter('city_id', $cityId)
            ->getQuery();
```

But my query is wrong, because there is no o.cities in Organizer table. Table contains only id and name.
[image]

Two entiries city and organizer have 3 tables in db:
Organizer
City
organizers_cities

In fact i need just to add in createQueryBuilder something like this:

```
SELECT Organizer . *
FROM Organizer
LEFT JOIN organizers_cities ON Organizer.id = organizers_cities.organizer_id
WHERE organizers_cities.city_id =25
```

i can solve it using:

```
$cityId = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:City')->findOneBy(array('link' => $citySlug))->getId();
        $city = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:City')->findOneBy(array(
            'link' => $citySlug,
        ));
       $organizers =  $city->getOrganizers();
        foreach ($organizers as $organizer){
            $pos = strpos($organizer, $partOfSearchText);
            if ($pos === false) {
                //do some things
            }
        }
```

, but it's ugly like hell

So,
How to achieve valid query?

City.php

```
  class City
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=140)
         */
        protected $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Organizer", mappedBy="cities")
         */
        protected $organizers;
        }
```

Organizer.php

```
  class Organizer
    {
        /**
         * @Groups({"jsonForCity", "questOrganizers"})
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=140)
         */
        protected $name;


        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\City", inversedBy="organizers")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="organizers_cities")
         *
         */
        protected $cities;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->quests = new ArrayCollection();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Organizers');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->innerJoin('o.cities', 'c')
        ->where('o.name LIKE :partOfSearchText')
        ->andWhere('c.id = :city_id')
        ->setParameter('partOfSearchText', '%'.$partOfSearchText.'%')
        ->setParameter('city_id', $cityId)
        ->getQuery();
```

More info: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html, http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: Thank you! One moment: With ->andWhere('IDENTITY(c) = :city_id') i got error http://imgur.com/YIz1ity . Fixed with ->andWhere('c.id = :city_id').